# PHP method()->method()->method()->

Tags: php, class, methods

How can I create Class in PHP, which will work like DB Class in codeIgniter ?

I can use this class in such a way:

```
$this->db->select('...');
$this->db->where('...');
$this->db->get('...');
```

and like that:

```
$this->db->select('...')->where('...')->get('...')-> .......
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is called a fluent interface / method chaining. Its easy to implement, but you have to be sure that you need it, since it is not always considered a good practice. http://ocramius.github.io/blog/fluent-interfaces-are-evil/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your methods return your current object:

```
public function method() {
    // ...
    return $this;
}
```

And by the way, it's called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 5):

Chaining like that is actually quite simple. You simply have each method return `$this`.

Answer (score 4):

Read [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

```
class User
{
   public function first()
   {
       return $this;
   }

   public function second()
   {
       return $this;
   }
}

$user = new User();
$user->first()->second();
```

Answer (score 1):

To you use the 'chaining', u should return the instance of the class, like this:

```
class Sql {

    protected $select ;
    protected $where ;
    protected $order ;

    public function select( $select ) {
        $this->select = $select ;
        //this is the secret
        return $this ;
    }

    public function where( $where ) {
        $this->where = $where ;
        //this is the secret
        return $this ;
    }

    public function order( $order ) {
        $this->order = $order ;
        //this is the secret
        return $this ;
    }

}

$sql = new Sql() ;

$sql->select( "MY_TABLE" )->where( "ID = 10" )->order( "name" ) ;

var_dump( $sql ) ;
```